# How to capture inactivityDelay based on user permissions

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Inside of this NextJS application there is a `permissions.tsx` file that looks like so:

```
// @ts-nocheck
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/client'

function usePermissions() {
const [permissions, setPermissions] = useState(null)
const [session] = useSession()

// All permission types
const [quickStart, setQuickStart] = useState(false)
const [briefIntro, seBriefIntro] = useState(false)
const [cheatSheet, setCheatSheet] = useState(false)
const [totalClinics, setTotalClinics] = useState(false)
const [asthmaControl, setAsthmaControl] = useState(false)
const [revenueProjection, setRevenueProjection] = useState(false)
const [revenueStats, setRevenueStats] = useState(false)
const [addNewPatient, setAddNewPatient] = useState(false)
const [searchPatient, setSearchPatient] = useState(false)
const [permissionPublicUserId, setPermissionPublicUserId] = useState(false)
const [billablePatientsCounter, setBillablePatientsCounter] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
setPermissions(session?.user?.componentPermissions)

setQuickStart(allow('armadillo.mainView.quickStartGuide.section'))
seBriefIntro(allow('armadillo.mainView.aBriefIntroduction.section'))
setCheatSheet(allow('armadillo.mainView.accessTheCheatSheet.section'))
setTotalClinics(allow('armadillo.patients.thisWeek.InOfficeOnboards.counter'))
setAsthmaControl(allow('armadillo.mainView.stats.asthmaControl.section'))
setRevenueProjection(
allow('armadillo.mainView.stats.revenewProjection.section')
)
setRevenueStats(allow('armadillo.mainView.stats.revenewStats.section'))
setAddNewPatient(allow('armadillo.patients.addNewPatient.button'))
setPermissionPublicUserId(allow('armadillo.users.publicUserId.label'))
setBillablePatientsCounter(
allow('armadillo.patients.lastLogin.newBillablePatients.counter')
)
}, [])

const allow = (permission) =>
session?.user?.componentPermissions?.includes(permission) || false // Be determinant.

return {
permissions,
quickStart,
briefIntro,
cheatSheet,
totalClinics,
asthmaControl,
revenueProjection,
revenueStats,
addNewPatient,
searchPatient,
permissionPublicUserId,
billablePatientsCounter,
}
}

export default usePermissions
```

The property of focus is the string `'armadillo.patients.lastLogin.newBillablePatients.counter'`. This string only exists for an account with billable patients, apparently. So I can use this as my boolean, but not entirely sure how, what I have tried has not worked.

I tried to set an if conditional inside another file which has a `useTimeout` hook that looks like so:

```
useTimeout(() => {
 resetBillinSessionTimeout()
 setIsIdle(true)
}, inactivityDelay)
```

So this timeout popup is kicked off after two minutes of inactivity, but only for users that are supposed to be doctors, for others it should never kick off this inactivity modal but it does. When I replace `inactivityDelay` with `null` the inactivity modal never appears, so that's why I am focused there.

Comment: are you missing a 'g' inside resetBillin_g_SessionTimeout() ?

Comment: @Dave, that was my mistake since I did not copy paste that piece of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the scenario, but perhaps something like this:

```
useTimeout(() => {
 resetBillinSessionTimeout()
 setIsIdle(true)
}, billablePatientsCounter ? inactivityDelay : null)
```

Only set the `inactivityDelay` for billable patients.

Comment: I marked your answer as the correct one, but I still need to use the `usePermission` import statement.